# The seconds of the Date I store in mySQL DB changes via CrudRepository

Tags: mysql, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using CrudRepository.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "StockMovement")
public class StockDateMovement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private Date fromDate;

    @Column
    private Date toDate;

}
```

Here is the test thats failing:

```
@Test
    void "findAll should find all stock date movement"(){
        Date today = new Date();
        Date tommorow = new Date()+1;
        StockDateMovement movement = new StockDateMovement(
            fromDate: today,
            toDate : tommorow
        )
        crudRepository.save(movement);
        assert crudRepository.findAll().contains(movement);
    }
```

The reason is as follows:

- toDate in movement object = Thu Sep 24 09:59:21 UTC 2015
- toDate returned from crud repo = 2015-09-24 09:59:22.0
- toDate actually stored in database column = 2015-09-24 09:59:22

**Note:** I have tried TemporalType.TIMESTAMP too but that doesn't help.

> Question: Why is this difference in seconds between the two dates? How
>   can I make my code take care of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java Date object has a precision level of milliseconds and the MySQL database stores timestamp with a precision of seconds. Hibernate itself rounds the milliseconds in Date object to seconds and puts it into the DB. Thus, the equals method of the entity should compare the Date objects by rounding off the date by seconds.

```
if (fromDate == null) {
            if (other.fromDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if(other.fromDate != null && DateUtils.round(fromDate, Calendar.SECOND).equals(DateUtils.round(other.fromDate, Calendar.SECOND)) == false) {
            return false;
        }
```